# mysql group by and sort each group

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by

I have the following table:

```
ID NAME TIME
1  A    0
2  A    3
3  B    1
```

I am using the query below which produces:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `NAME`
```

```
ID NAME TIME
1  A    0
3  B    1
```

And I want use `GROUP BY` to generate a result like this (discount sort by the TIME column):

```
ID NAME TIME
2  A    3
3  B    1
```

Comment: By reading your question, it is little unclear of how you want the fields to be sorted.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what result exactly you are trying to get. Perhaps try articulating *what* you actually want to do.

Comment: But what if I want "order by" go natural order?

Answer (score 28):

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(TIME) as TIME 
FROM table 
GROUP BY time 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: This actually worked for me. It gets me less info than the subquery-based solutions, but it's faster.

Comment: There is no assurance that the `NAME` column will be from the same row as `MAX(TIME)`. It may well work given the above data or a small dataset but is by no means reliable. For a thorough discussion see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by?noredirect=1#comment63515985_14770671

Comment: It's work! Seems only `ORDER BY` clause can accept the alias in `SELECT` clause, nice trick.

Comment: Agree Rob Forrest's comment. You may get bug by this query depend on your use case.

Comment: It does not work for big data. `ORDER BY` is sorting the final result after `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 7):

```
 select * from (select * from table order by TIME DESC) t group by NAME
```

Comment: It will not work proper in my opinion, grupuping will be always the same, with and without DESC

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution from here http://www.cafewebmaster.com/mysql-order-sort-group, it was able to solve my problem too :)

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM 

(
select * from `my_table` order by timestamp desc
) as my_table_tmp

group by catid

order by nid desc
```

Answer (score 4):

To get rows with highest time per group you could use a self join

```
select a.*
from demo a 
left join demo b on a.NAME =b.NAME and a.TIME < b.TIME
where b.NAME is null;
```

OR

```
select a.*
from demo a 
join (
  select NAME, max(`TIME`) as `TIME`
  from demo
  group by NAME
) b on a.NAME =b.NAME and a.TIME = b.TIME;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ac0706/4)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to decide what you want to see in the ID and the time fields after the group by. As an example I'll select the MAX(ID) and the SUM(time), then order by totaltime desc.

```
SELECT MAX(id), name, SUM(time) AS totaltime
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY totaltime DESC
```

Hope this helps.