# MySQL select GROUP BY order

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a mysql statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_messages 
WHERE to_user_id = '$user_id' OR from_user_id = '$user_id' 
GROUP BY from_user_id 
ORDER BY date_sent DESC
```

and it is producing the correct results however they are not in the correct order.

The grouping works well but it record displayed in the group is the first recorded entered into the DB but I would like the latest record to be displayed in each group.

Is there a way to have the latest record displayed for each group?

```
2011-12-19 12:16:25 This is the first message
2011-12-19 12:18:20 This is the second message
2011-12-19 12:43:04 This is the third message
```

The group shows 'This is the first message' where I would like 'This is the third message' as that is the most recent record/message.

Cheers

Comment: What is the query supposed to show?

Comment: If you need the two columns only (e.g. ID and its latest timestamp), this might work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4448536/722036. It's **faster** than using sub-queries on a huge table with millions of rows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may work (but not guaranteed):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  ( SELECT *
    FROM tbl_messages 
    WHERE to_user_id = '$user_id' OR from_user_id = '$user_id' 
    ORDER BY date_sent DESC
  ) tmp
GROUP BY from_user_id 
ORDER BY date_sent DESC
```

---

This should work:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM 
    tbl_messages AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT from_user_id 
           , MAX(date_sent) AS max_date_sent
      FROM tbl_messages 
      WHERE to_user_id = '$user_id' OR from_user_id = '$user_id' 
      GROUP BY from_user_id 
    ) AS tg
    ON  (tg.from_user_id, tg.max_date_sent) = (t.from_user_id, t.date_sent)
ORDER BY t.date_sent DESC
```

Comment: This seems to be working. A slight modification needed (add tbl_messages before the GROUP BY) but looks good. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks save my day, in school I learned more about subquerys... I did not remember this greats querys ... my teacher ... old memories

Answer (score 8):

Do a GROUP BY after the ORDER BY by wrapping your query with the GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC) t GROUP BY t.from
```

Comment: Even if I put the ASC in the  query "t" its taking DESC.

Answer (score 2):

If your messages table has a primary key that is auto-increment, and all messages are by nature highest number is the most recent date... However, since I don't KNOW that, I am going based on the MAX( date_sent ) instead of max( SomeIDKey ), but the principle is the same.

```
select
      tm2.*
   from
      ( select tm1.from_user_id, 
               max( tm1.date_sent ) LatestMsgDate
           from tbl_messages tm1
           group by tm1.from_user_id ) MaxPerUser

      left join tbl_messages tm2
         on MaxPerUser.From_User_ID = tm2.From_User_ID
        AND MaxPerUser.LatestMsgDat = tm2.Date_Sent

   order by
      date_sent DESC
```

Comment: how would I add ORDER BY in MaxPerUser and GROUP BY at the end of the query.

Comment: @MohammedAbrarAhmed, no order by applicable to the inner MaxPerUser query.  However, if you wanted your outer results based on the most recent message date, you could ORDER BY MaxPerUser.LatestMsgDate -- if that is what you are considering to have the most recent messages float to the top.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_messages WHERE to_user_id = '$user_id' OR from_user_id = '$user_id' GROUP BY from_user_id ORDER BY from_user_id, date_sent DESC
```