# MySQL sorting by date with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, left-join, max

My table `titles` looks like this

```
id |group|date                |title
---+-----+--------------------+--------
1  |1    |2012-07-26 18:59:30 | Title 1
2  |1    |2012-07-26 19:01:20 | Title 2
3  |2    |2012-07-26 19:18:15 | Title 3
4  |2    |2012-07-26 20:09:28 | Title 4
5  |2    |2012-07-26 23:59:52 | Title 5
```

I need latest result from each group ordered by date in descending order. Something like this

```
id |group|date                |title
---+-----+--------------------+--------
5  |2    |2012-07-26 23:59:52 | Title 5
2  |1    |2012-07-26 19:01:20 | Title 2
```

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM `titles`
GROUP BY `group`
ORDER BY MAX( `date` ) DESC
```

but I'm geting first results from groups. Like this

```
id |group|date                |title
---+-----+--------------------+--------
3  |2    |2012-07-26 18:59:30 | Title 3
1  |1    |2012-07-26 19:18:15 | Title 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is this query going to be more complicated if I use LEFT JOIN?

Comment: If you need the two columns only (e.g. ID and its latest timestamp), this might work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4448536/722036. It's **faster** than using sub-queries on a huge table with millions of rows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This page](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) was very helpful to me; it taught me how to use self-joins to get the max/min/something-n rows per group.

In your situation, it can be applied to the effect you want like so:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT group, MAX(date) AS date FROM titles GROUP BY group)
AS x JOIN titles USING (group, date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this topic via Google, looked like I had the same issue.
Here's my own solution if, like me, you don't like subqueries :

```
-- Create a temporary table like the output
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE titles_tmp LIKE titles;

-- Add a unique key on where you want to GROUP BY
ALTER TABLE titles_tmp ADD UNIQUE KEY `group` (`group`);

-- Read the result into the tmp_table. Duplicates won't be inserted.
INSERT IGNORE INTO titles_tmp
  SELECT *
    FROM `titles`
    ORDER BY  `date` DESC;

-- Read the temporary table as output
SELECT * 
  FROM titles_tmp
  ORDER BY `group`;
```

It has a way better performance. Here's how to increase speed if the date_column has the same order as the auto_increment_one (you then don't need an ORDER BY statement) :

```
-- Create a temporary table like the output
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE titles_tmp LIKE titles;

-- Add a unique key on where you want to GROUP BY
ALTER TABLE titles_tmp ADD UNIQUE KEY `group` (`group`);

-- Read the result into the tmp_table, in the natural order. Duplicates will update the temporary table with the freshest information.
INSERT INTO titles_tmp
  SELECT *
    FROM `titles`

  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE  `id`    = VALUES(`id`), 
            `date`  = VALUES(`date`), 
            `title` = VALUES(`title`);

-- Read the temporary table as output
SELECT * 
  FROM titles_tmp
  ORDER BY `group`;
```

Result :

```
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+
| id | group | date                | title   |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+
|  2 |     1 | 2012-07-26 19:01:20 | Title 2 |
|  5 |     2 | 2012-07-26 23:59:52 | Title 5 |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+
```

On large tables this method makes a significant point in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if dates are unique in a group this would work (if not, you'll see several rows that match the max date in a group). (Also, bad naming of columns, 'group', 'date' might give you syntax errors and such specially 'group')

```
select t1.* from titles t1, (select group, max(date) date from titles group by group) t2
where t2.date = t1.date
and t1.group = t2.group
order by date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make use of MySQL user variables to identify a "control break" in the `group` values.

If you can live with an extra column being returned, something like this will work:

```
SELECT IF(s.group = @prev_group,0,1) AS latest_in_group
     , s.id
     , @prev_group := s.group AS `group`
     , s.date
     , s.title
  FROM (SELECT t.id,t.group,t.date,t.title
          FROM titles t
         ORDER BY t.group DESC, t.date DESC, t.id DESC
       ) s
  JOIN (SELECT @prev_group := NULL) p
HAVING latest_in_group = 1
 ORDER BY s.group DESC
```

What this is doing is ordering all the rows by `group` and by `date` in descending order. (We specify DESC on all the columns in the ORDER BY, in case there is an index on `(group,date,id)` that MySQL can do a "reverse scan" on. The inclusion of the `id` column gets us deterministic (repeatable) behavior, in the case when there are more than one row with the latest `date` value.) That's the inline view aliased as `s`.

The "trick" we use is to compare the `group` value to the `group` value from the previous row. Whenever we have a different value, we know that we are starting a "new" group, and that this row is the "latest" row (we have the IF function return a 1).  Otherwise (when the group values match), it's not the latest row (and we have the IF function returns a 0).

Then, we filter out all the rows that don't have that `latest_in_group` set as a 1.

It's possible to remove that extra column by wrapping that query (as an inline view) in another query:

```
SELECT r.id
     , r.group
     , r.date
     , r.title
  FROM ( SELECT IF(s.group = @prev_group,0,1) AS latest_in_group
              , s.id
              , @prev_group := s.group AS `group`
              , s.date
              , s.title
           FROM (SELECT t.id,t.group,t.date,t.title
                   FROM titles t
                  ORDER BY t.group DESC, t.date DESC, t.id DESC
                ) s
           JOIN (SELECT @prev_group := NULL) p
         HAVING latest_in_group = 1
       ) r
 ORDER BY r.group DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` field is an auto-incrementing field, and it's safe to say that the highest value of the `id` field is also the highest value for the `date` of any group, then this is a simple solution:

```
SELECT   b.*
FROM     (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM titles GROUP BY group) a
JOIN     titles b ON a.maxid = b.id
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mysql query to get latest updated/inserted record from table.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  select * from `titles` order by `date` desc
) as tmp_table
group by `group`
order by `date` desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to get the most recent record from each group

```
SELECT 
T1.* FROM
(SELECT 
    MAX(ID) AS maxID
FROM
    T2
GROUP BY Type) AS aux
    INNER JOIN
T2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = aux.maxID ;
```

Where ID is your auto increment field and Type is the type of records, you wanted to group by.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses an dumb extension of `GROUP BY` which is not reliable if you want to get such results therefore, you could use

```
select id, group, date, title from titles as t where id = 
(select id from titles where group = a.group order by date desc limit 1);
```

In this query, each time the table is scanned full for each group so it can find the most recent date. I could not find any better alternate for this. Hope this will help someone.