# Dynamic column, one value, GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, group-by

I need to develop a private messages system between users and here is what I want to do :

I have a table like the following :

```
id | from_user_id | to_user_id | message
1  | 1            | 2          | Hey n°1 !    <-- Me with user n°2
2  | 2            | 1          | Hey n°2 !    <-- Me with user n°2
4  | 1            | 3          | Hey n°3 !    <-- Me with user n°3
3  | 3            | 2          | Hey n°4 !
```

We suppose that I'm the user n°1, I want to get a list of my last messages "group by users" and ordered by id, as discussions :

```
id | with_user_id | message
4  | 3            | Hey n°3 !
2  | 2            | Hey n°2 !
```

I've tried a request like :

```
SELECT id, message,
       (CASE WHEN from_user_id = 1 THEN to_user_id ELSE from_user_id END) AS with_user_id
FROM privates
WHERE from_user_id = 1 OR to_user_id = 1
GROUP BY with_user_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But I'm getting this :

```
id | with_user_id | message
4  | 3            | Hey n°3 !
1  | 2            | Hey n°1 !
```

So the problem is that it selects the first message with user n°1 and not the last.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I made a mistake with my syntax, give me some time and I will post a working answer.

Comment: You answer was right ! I've just added "ORDER BY SQ.id DESC" at the end and it works !

Comment: Oh,  you must be using MySQL then  as MSSQL doesn't allow an order by in the subquery.  Well if it worked I will repost the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This will not work in MSSQL as OrderBy clauses are not allowed in sub queries. you can use a method similar to the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by) question if you are using MSSQL.

You need to apply the order by before the group by, because the group by statement is grouping messages 1 and 2 together and picking the first. Try something like this:

```
Select SQ.*
FROM (
    SELECT id, message,
       (CASE WHEN from_user_id = 1 THEN to_user_id ELSE from_user_id END) AS with_user_id
    FROM privates
    WHERE from_user_id = 1 OR to_user_id = 1
    ORDER BY id DESC
) AS SQ
GROUP BY SQ.with_user_id
```

Ordering in this way will get only the most recent message for a given conversation.

Answer (score 0):

look like you need all messages for creating dialog with user, try following select

```
select id, from_user_id, to_user_id, message,
  from privates
 where from_user_id = 1
    or to_user_id = 1
 order by case
              when from_user_id = 1 then
               to_user_id
              else
               from_user_id
          end,
          id desc
```