# From Select in doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm

How do I do this in doctrine2 QB or DQL.

SELECT * FROM

(
select * from `my_table` order by timestamp desc
) as my_table_tmp

group by catid

order by nid desc

Comment: You should'n use `ORDER BY` in a subselect, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14770936/1162392.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is the same as:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
GROUP BY catid
    HAVING timestamp = MAX(timestamp)
ORDER BY nid DESC
;
```

If it is correct, then you should be able to do:

```
$qb->select('e')
    ->from('My\Entities\Table', 'e')
    ->groupBy('e.catid')
    ->having('e.timestamp = MAX(e.timestamp)')
    ->orderBy('nid', 'DESC')
;
```

Or, directly using DQL:

```
SELECT e
FROM My\Entities\Table e
GROUP BY e.catid
    HAVING e.timestamp = MAX(e.timestamp)
ORDER BY e.nid DESC
;
```

Hope this helps and works! ;)