# SELECT the oldest of the most recent lines

Tags: mysql

I have a table storing the scores (with the date) of players they did at each game.

```
Example:
john  154  10/02/2014
mat   178  09/02/2014
eric  270  08/02/2014
mat   410  07/02/2014
john  155  06/02/2014
```

In this example I want "eric 270 08/02/2014" because thins is the oldest of the most recents.
Which request must I do to retrieve that ?

Comment: What is the "most recent"?

Comment: ...And how is 08/02/2014 the oldest record among those you listed (whether it is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy)?

Comment: Can you further explain your question. Why don't you want to select 'mat 410 07/02/2014'? Since that is an older score.

Comment: sorry, yes it's dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I want eric because "mat 401 07/02/2014" is older than "mat 178 09/02/2014"

Comment: @Greg2fs As I understand your question you want from the *most recent scores by user* the oldest one.

Comment: I gave an example because it's hard for me to explain in english. Maybe it will be easier in 2 requests, the first one to get the most recent ones: (john  154  10/02/2014, mat   178  09/02/2014, eric  270  08/02/2014) and the second to get the oldest: eric  270  08/02/2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you request the oldest entry among the set containing the most recent one of each user.

In such a case, you can deal with your problem using a subquery given the last date for each user, then used in the main query to select and sort only the most recent entry of each user.

```
SELECT scores.* 
FROM scores
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT max(date) last, name
  FROM scores
  GROUP BY name
) last_temp_table
ON scores.name = last_temp_table.name
AND scores.date = last_temp_table.last
ORDER BY scores.date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

More info in different SO threads such as [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Comment: This seems to me the correct approach, only you've got to sort ASC to get the oldest one of the recents.

Comment: @VMai thanks you for pointing out my mistake on the sorting order. I just edit it.

Comment: I just tried that: SELECT * FROM (SELECT max(date) last, name
  FROM scores
  GROUP BY name) AS lasts ORDER BY last ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: @Greg2fs With a simplified query like yours, you won't get the score right. Please have a look at the comments in my fiddle.

Comment: I don't see what's the problem, also like that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/262a1/7/0 it seems working without subquery, can you explain ?

Comment: Ok, I undestood you explaination and your query, thank you very much.

Comment: Just one more question, assuming the scores are taken from another table (games) can it include results that have no score yet (no row in games)

Comment: You can join two tables with LEFT JOIN. The query then returns all the rows of the left table even if there is no related rows in the right one.

Comment: Yes but then I get everything... I found (something like) that: `SELECT * 
FROM players,scores
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT max(date) last, name
  FROM scores,players
  GROUP BY name
) last_temp_table
ON scores.date = last_temp_table.last 
WHERE (players.name = last_temp_table.name OR scores.date IS NULL)
ORDER BY scores.date ASC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: still miss some results, even with LEFT JOIN :-(

Comment: it should works : `SELECT * FROM players LEFT JOIN (scores INNER JOIN (SELECT max(scores.date) last, name FROM scores GROUP BY name) last_temp_table ON last_temp_table.last=scores.date and last_temp_table.name=scores.name) ON players.name=scores.name ORDER BY scores.date ASC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

The question as worded doesn't make much sense unless you define **most recent**.

If I assume that you have some criteria like: "Give the oldest event that happened within the last 3 days" then that is a simple matter of ordering and limiting across a date range.

```
select * from events where ts >= CURDATE() - 3
 order by ts asc
  limit 1
```