# Selecting latest entries for distinct entry

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a brain fart as to how I would do this.
I need to select only the latest entry in a group of same id entries

I have records in an appointment table.

```
  lead_id   app_id
     4        42
     3        43
     1        44
     2        45
     2        46 (want this one)
     1        48
     3        49 (this one)
     4        50 (this one)
     1        51 (this one)
```

The results I require are app_id 46,49,50,51

Only the latest entries in the appointment table, based on duplicate lead_id identifiers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is much more optimal and efficient way of doing it (sorting next grouping):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM appointment
    ORDER BY lead_id, app_id DESC 
) AS ord
GROUP BY lead_id
```

this will be useful when you need all other fields too from the table without complicated queries

**Result:**

```
lead_id     app_id
1           51
2           46
3           49
4           50
```

Comment: thanks....cuz yes....I did need all the fields.  I shoulda mentioned that in my post

Comment: even if you use an ORDER BY in your subquery, the values returned will be indeterminate http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Is this true?  What do you mean by indeterminate?

Comment: no he's not, he just don't understand how does sub-querying works :p

Comment: @KyleK yes, it is a trick that is used often and it looks like it always work, but as the documentations says it's better not to rely on it. The correct answer is Joel's.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili it has been discussed often here on SO and it's a trick it's better not to use. Maybe it will work on current version of MySQL but things might change on future versions and you will get into trouble. Some other implementations of MySQL like MariaDB will already return wrong result.

Comment: see for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by

Comment: So ther you would mention this too: `My question is a simple one then: Is there anyway to order rows before grouping without resorting to a subquery?` but you did not read question carefully, just trying to defense your wrong opinion with anything

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili the author of the question is making your same mistake. But did you read the accepted answer with 60 upvotes?

Comment: that problem is much different, there is field `post_date` which may have duplicate values (and this would not always return same result even for simple select query). so ordering with such columns may vary, will not go deeper for the case. but now we have not such a situation. in our case `app_id` is unique and there will not be two `51`s @fthiella

Comment: @fthiella also he starts hes answer by: `Using an ORDER BY in a subquery is not the best solution to this problem.` so that means it depends on the problem, then I would say, any query may depend on the required task, and not always have guaranted results

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Is there a performance difference between your solution and the one with a `GROUP BY` in the subquery and the `ORDER BY` clause on the result? I never tried your approach because i've the impression of having less "control" on the data (it'll certainly works here but if i want the exact same kind of result on a different table where `app_id` is not unique, the result will probably not be the expected one...)

Comment: @JoëlSalamin your solution is the only one documented and certified, using ORDER BY/GROUP BY with non-aggregated column is considered bad practice and there are no guarantees that it will always work

Comment: this got too messy, this is not fair, and shame on down voters. your minds can't for out of theories

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT A.lead_id
    ,MAX(A.app_id) AS [last_app_id]
FROM appointment A
GROUP BY A.lead_id
```

If you want to have every columns corresponding to these expected rows:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM appointment A
INNER JOIN (SELECT A2.lead_id
                ,MAX(A2.app_id) AS [last_app_id]
            FROM appointment A2
            GROUP BY A2.lead_id) M ON M.lead_id = A.lead_id
                                     AND M.last_app_id = A.app_id
ORDER BY A.lead_id
```

Here i simply use the previous query for a jointure in order to get only the desired rows.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by George Garchagudashvili is not a good answer, because it has `group by` with unaggregated columns in the `select`.  `Select *` with `group by` is simply something that should not be allowed in SQL -- and it isn't in almost all databases.  Happily, the default version of the more recent versions of MySQL also rejects this syntax.

An efficient solution is:

```
select a.*
from appointment a
where a.app_id = (select max(a2.app_id)
                  from appointment a2
                  where a2.lead_id = a.lead_id
                 );
```

With an index on `appointment(lead_id, app_id)`, this should be as fast or faster than George's query.