# Select 10 latest comments with unique author from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I`ve got MySQL table with such columns: comment_id, comment_content, comment_date, comment_author.
I need to get 10 latest comments which have unique comment_author.
This query:

```
SELECT comment_content, comment_date, comment_author
FROM comments   
GROUP BY comment_author
ORDER BY comment_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

doing almost what i need, but it takes 1 oldest comment from each unique author, but i need the latest one. Tried to use GROUP BY comments_author HAVING MAX(comment_date) but nothing changed.
Thank you.

Comment: maybe this might help you? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by

Comment: Your query seems to be perfect,.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.JAVA.net We have very different definitions of perfection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` to achieve this

```
select
c1.comment_content,
c1.comment_date,
c1.comment_author
from comments c1
left join comments c2 on c1.comment_author = c2.comment_author
and c1.comment_date < c2.comment_date
where c2.comment_author is null 
order by c1.comment_date desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.comment_content, c.comment_date, c.comment_author
FROM comments c 
INNER JOIN (SELECT comment_author, MAX(comment_date) AS comment_date
            FROM comments
            GROUP BY comment_author
           ) A ON c.comment_author = A.comment_author AND c.comment_date = A.comment_date
ORDER BY c.comment_date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

1. Fetch records for all comment_author with latest date so check my inner query.
2. Then Fetch the required data from main table by joining on comment_author and maximum date

Comment: Can you please specify what your inner & overall query does ? Its usful for upcoming visitors.