# MySQL ORDER BY FIELD before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I would like to be able to have my result set sorted by field `id`, and then filter out duplicate values on column `name`.

Given a table

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | other |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 |    a |     1 |
|  2 |    a |     0 |
|  3 |    b |     0 |
|  4 |    c |     0 |
+----+------+-------+
```

My sorting will be the following: `2, 4, 1, 3`.
Consequently, I desire the result to look like:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | other |
+----+------+-------+
|  2 |    a |     0 |
|  4 |    c |     0 |
|  3 |    b |     0 |
+----+------+-------+
```

After all, in the sorted result set, the row with `id = 2` appears before the row with `id = 1`, while they share a `name`. In such case, only the first `name` should be preserved.

In short:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2, 4, 1, 3)
GROUP BY name
```

Unfortunately, it appears MySQL chooses which of the rows that turned out to contain a non-unique `name` it returns, regardless of the ordering done.

I have read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by), but it only covers ordering by `DESC` (and indirectly `ASC`), but not by `FIELD`.

What would be the way to return only the first row in case of duplicates for a certain column while taking into account the sorting algorithm?

Comment: `I desire the result to look like` - you can use `DISTINCT` keyword, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Ivan No there can be other columns with values that are not the same per se and which are allowed to be different