# Multi-Dimensional groupBy & orderBy before Paginate - Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, group-by

What I want to do is grouping comments written by a user with same subjects, and get the latest (most-recent) one. I tried using `Comment::where()->orderBy()->groupBy()`, but it isn't returning data as expected.

This is my database:

```
| id | receiver_id | sender_id | title | body | created_at |
| 13 |      2      |     5     |  Art  |  DD  |   12.30... |
| 12 |      2      |     5     |  Art  |  CC  |   12.20... |
| 11 |      2      |     5     |  Art  |  BB  |   12.10... |
| 10 |      2      |     5     |  Art  |  AA  |   12.00... |

| 9  |      2      |     3     |  Msc  |  XX  |   11.30... |
| 8  |      2      |     3     |  Msc  |  YY  |   11.20... |
| 7  |      2      |     3     |  Msc  |  ZZ  |   11.10... |

| 6  |      2      |     2     |  Foo  |  UU  |   10.40... |
| 5  |      2      |     2     |  Foo  |  II  |   10.30... |

| 4  |      2      |     2     |  You  |  QQ  |   10.20... |
| 3  |      2      |     2     |  You  |  WW  |   10.10... |

| 2  |      2      |     3     |  Msc  |  LL  |   10.00... |

| 1  |      2      |     4     |  CSS  |  VV  |   10.30... |
| 0  |      2      |     4     |  CSS  |  NN  |   10.20... |
```

I realised that, created_at and ids are in the same order. So, I decided using `id desc`, as I may have trouble arranging date integers in `created_at` strings. This is what I tried:

```
$comment = Comment::where('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
                  ->orderBy('id','desc')
                  ->groupBy('sender_id', 'title')
                  ->paginate(5);
dd($comment);
```

The result I want to get is this:

> `0 => Comment { id = 13, sender_id = 5, title = Art, body = DD }`  *(latest created_at)*
>
> `1 => Comment { id = 9, sender_id = 3, title = Msc, body = XX }`
>
> `2 => Comment { id = 6, sender_id = 2, title = Foo, body = UU }`
>
> `3 => Comment { id = 4, sender_id = 2, title = You, body = QQ }`
>
> `4 => Comment { id = 1, sender_id = 4, title = CSS, body = VV }`

However this is showing something like:

> `0 => Comment { id = 10, sender_id = 5, title = Art, body = AA }`
>
> `1 => Comment { id = 5, sender_id = 2, title = Foo, body = II }`
>
> `2 => Comment { id = 3, sender_id = 2, title = You, body = WW }`
>
> `3 => Comment { id = 2, sender_id = 3, title = Msc, body = LL }`
>
> `4 => Comment { id = 0, sender_id = 4, title = CSS, body = NN }`

- It's giving the latest comments but gets the earliest one.
- It's completely skipping User User-3 and shows User-2's 2x subject
- Then it shows User-3 here, after finishing User2's 2x subjects instead of after 'Art'.

When I remove `->paginate()` and try `->toSql()` in my above query, I receive:

```
"select * from `comments` where `receiver_id` = ? group by `title`, `sender_id` order by `id` desc"
```

I think the `order by id desc` part is getting created in the wrong position, so this may cause the problem. But, I'm not sure.

Also, when I swap the places of `->orderBy()` and `->groupBy` like `->groupBy()` first, then `->orderBy()`, it returns exactly same result.

Lastly, I tried replacing `->orderBy('title', 'sender_id')`, but again same result.

What I am doing wrong or missing out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is about mysql group by is excuted before order by.

solution should have a inner join:

```
Comment::join(\DB::raw('(select max(id) as id from comments group by sender_id) t'),function($join){
                  $join->on('comments.id', '=', 't.id');
})->where('comments.receiver_id', Auth::user()->id)
  ->orderBy('id','desc')
  ->paginate(5);
```

similar here:

[MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Comment: I receive `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't' in 'on clause'` for some reason when I try your example. `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `comments` inner join (select max(id) from comments group by sender_id) t on `comments`.`id` = `t` where `comments.receiver_id` = Test)`. I understand your method, but I just couldn't figure out how to apply it, because this is giving error

Comment: @senty,fixed, miss as id statement

Comment: Thanks! This took me a big step forward. It's successfully combining users together. However, I want to have an entry for where, both sender_id & subject is same. So, I want to have 2 separate elements for ids `6&5` and `3&4` because they have different subjects