# Mysql group by after order by?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

There are few question like this, but they are not constructed in a simple way that make the answer accessible to more generic cases. These question were built for specific cases.

Suppose we have a table

```
id  letter
----------
1   a
2   a
3   b
4   b
5   a
```

how do we get this result ?

```
1   a   2
3   b   2
5   a   1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL order by before group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Answer (score 2):

basically you need to know when you have a new "row" to group off of. I am ranking them off of the changed letters

```
select min(id), letter, sum(my_count)
from (
    select 
        id, letter, count(id) as my_count,
        @rank := if (@letter = letter, @rank, @rank + 1) as rank,
        @letter := letter
    from test
    cross join (select @rank := 0, @letter := '') t
    group by id
) t
group by rank;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fee3/1)