# MySQL: Multiple Group By With Desc Order Issue

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I already visited [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by) for Single Group By it's working fine. I have issue with 2 group by columns.

I have below table named "messages". Messages are comments of User's Posts

```
id | posts_id | from_user_id | to_user_id | message_description | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      1           1              2             test1             2016-09-06 10:00:00
2      1           1              2             test2             2016-09-06 11:00:00
3      1           4              2             test3             2016-09-06 09:00:00
4      1           4              2             test4             2016-09-06 15:00:00
5      2           1              2             test1             2016-09-06 10:00:00
6      2           1              2             test2             2016-09-06 11:00:00
7      2           4              2             test3             2016-09-06 09:00:00
8      2           4              2             test4             2016-09-06 15:00:00
```

Query's Result Output Should Be

```
id | posts_id | from_user_id | to_user_id | message_description | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2      1           1              2             test2             2016-09-06 11:00:00
4      1           4              2             test4             2016-09-06 15:00:00
6      2           1              2             test2             2016-09-06 11:00:00
8      2           4              2             test4             2016-09-06 15:00:00
```

What i'm trying to retrieve post wise & user wise their latest messages.

I gave tried below, but it's not giving result in correct order.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE to_user_id = '2'
GROUP BY posts_id DESC,
         from_user_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: @Strawberry i already visited that post. But it's for single group by only, i have to use 2 group by columns in that way not able to get answer

Comment: Hmm. I don't think this is a group by/ order by question at all since the requirement seems to be to get the last entry per from_user_id. Try this SELECT t1.*
FROM messages t1
WHERE t1.id = (select max(id) from messages t2 where t2.posts_id = t1.posts_id and t2.from_user_id = t1.from_user_id)

Comment: You have 3 users, but you only seem to want to return messages relating to one of them (user 2)

Comment: Many many thanks @P.Salmon This is the answer i'm looking for. Solved :)

Comment: @Strawberry still it's duplicate??

Comment: I'm not yet convinced that it's not a duplicate. P.Salmon has simply substituted a correlated subquery for an uncorellated one.

Comment: Your result set is 'user wise' only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is identical to thousands of others posted on SO. An optimal solution, as discussed in the manual, is an uncorellated subquery, e.g.:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) id 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE to_user_id = 2 -- OPTIONAL
        GROUP 
           BY from_user_id
     ) y 
    ON y.id = x.id;
```

Comment: Where to use posts_id?? It's giving error Unknown column 'y.id'

Comment: Posts id is not  required here, but I've added the to_user_id.

Comment: I think it's required. Please check update question with "messages" table data & still giving "Unknown column ON y.id" error

Comment: I see. You want the latest message per user, per post. There was only one post in your original data set, so that wasn't very clear. Anyway, it's a trivial change...

Comment: Yes. Messages should be per post user wise. So for one Post i will get different messages user wise.

Comment: No. I still don't understand what that means.

Comment: Let me explain: For one Blog Post, different users will post messages/comments. In the Message module listing, what i have to display Post Title, With Latest Comments Date & Username

Comment: But your result set only shows one post. Why is post 2 not shown?