# MySQL GROUP BY w/ ORDER BY not having desired result

Tags: mysql

I have a query that attempts to retrieve IDs of people, but only if those people have more than one address. I'm also checking that the last time I called them was at least 30 days ago. Finally, I'm trying to order the results, because I want to pull up results with the oldest last_called datetime:

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM
  people p 
  LEFT JOIN addresses a 
    ON p.id = a.id 
WHERE p.last_called <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY p.last_called ASC 
LIMIT 25
```

Right now, the results are not excluding people with only one address. I haven't even got to the point where I know if the sort order is correct, but right now I'd just like to know why it is that my query isn't pulling up results where there is at least 2 addresses for the person.

Comment: Do you want to include people with no address as well?

Comment: @DarshanMehta, all people have at least one address.

Comment: Include `p.last_called` in the select clause. You are grouping by that after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to include people with no address then I would recommend using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and `DISTINCT` to get distinct address ids 
(just in case if you have duplicate mappings), e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)) AS cnt 
FROM
  people p 
  JOIN addresses a 
    ON p.id= a.peopleid 
WHERE p.last_called <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)) > 1
```

As far as `Ordering` is concerned, MySQL evaluates `GROUP BY` before ordering the results and hence, you need to wrap the query inside another query to get the ordered results.

**Update**

Instead of joining on aid, you need to join on `peopleId` of an address record to get the people record.

Comment: I'm not getting any results from that query. I removed the ordering so my query is just like yours, and nothing ...

Comment: I had to drop DISTINCT for it to start returning results. You had no way to know that the a.id is not primary or unique, so I think that's why you were using it. Anyways, I've got that handled. What about the sorting? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by