# Laravel query doesn't want to select last one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I tried distinct before but somehow my query won't select the last comment. He always select the oldest comment. Then i tried it with groupBy instead of distinct. But this won't work either.

My current query:

```
\App\Comment::limit(5)->groupBy('comments.id')
            ->orderBy('comments.id', 'desc')
            ->join('topics', 'comments.topic_id', '=', 'comments.id')
            ->select('comments.user_id', 'topics.id', 'topics.name')
            ->whereIn('topics.cat_id', $cats)
            ->where([['comments.removed', '=', false],['topics.removed', '=', false]])
            ->get();
```

It's pretty long.
Hopfully someone can explain me why this won't work.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @avonnadozie sorry die nu bad explaination I want to select 5 topics based on the last comments.

Comment: No wait I want to select the last comments where the topic isn't removed and is in the chosen categories

Comment: Update your question to show these

Comment: You say you want comments, but you are selecting topics. I guess you want 5 most recent topics with the user_id of the latest comment. Please explain exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors found so far

1. groupBy is not needed
2. Your join statement `join('topics', 'comments.topic_id', '=', 'comments.id')` should be joining columns in table `comments` and `topics`

Fix

```
\App\Comment::select('comments.user_id', 'topics.id', 'topics.name')
    ->join('topics', 'comments.topic_id', 'topics.id')
    ->whereIn('topics.cat_id', $cats)
    ->where('comments.removed', false)
    ->where('topics.removed', false)
    ->latest('comments.id')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

PS: `latest('comments.id')` is handy for `orderBy('comments.id', 'desc')`

**UPDATE**

To get the latest comment for at most 5 recently updated topics, try this

```
\App\Comment::select('comments.user_id', 'topics.id', 'topics.name')
    ->from(DB::raw("(select * from comments where removed = 0 order by id desc) as comments"))
    ->join('topics', 'comments.topic_id', 'topics.id')
    ->whereIn('topics.cat_id', $cats)
    ->where('topics.removed', false)
    ->groupBy('topics.id')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

Comment: This solution looks clean but gives every latest comment also if those 2 are in 1 topic. it also needs to be filtert on comments.topic_id

Comment: If you want to return only one comment per topic, then group by `topics.id`

Comment: Then that problem is back then i get the oldest comment instead of the newest one.

Comment: Have you tried the solution? Having fixed the join and grouping by `topics.id` instead of  `comments.id`, the output should change

Comment: I think this trend has what you are looking for [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Comment: Looking in to that but can't really get it to work :(

Comment: You can create the subquery like this `->from(DB::raw("(select * from comments order by id desc) as comments"))`, see this sample code https://pastebin.com/PawTLQyw

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `whereHas`. You should do something like this:

```
\App\Comment::where('removed', false)
            ->whereHas('topic', function($q) use ($cats) {
                $q->where('removed', false)
                  ->whereIn('cat_id', $cats);
            })
            ->limit(5)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

To achieve this, you must have the relations established by functions, such as `topics` (ie: hasMany) in `Comment` model.

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::topics() the relations are there commet has a belongs to topic and topic has a hasmany comments

Comment: If comment belongs to topic, try only `whereHas('topic', function($q) {`.

Comment: whereIn('topics.cat_id', $cats) topics.cat_id doesn;t exist there because join isn;t use and if i add whereIn to the $q it can't reach the variable $cats?

Comment: I've edited the answer, you must use `use ($cats)` to make it available in the function. Try it again, please