# Get latest record using multiple column values

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table that stores user purchase history:

Table `Purchases` : `id`, `user`, `brand`, `model`, `color`, `date`

I'd like to get a list of latest purchases made by a user, grouped by brand and model.

Here is an example dataset:

```
1, Bob,  Apple,   iPhone 6, Gold,   2017-01-03
2, Bob,  Apple,   iPhone 6, Silver, 2017-01-09
3, Bob,  Apple,   iPhone 6, Gold,   2017-01-18
4, Bob,  Samsung, Galaxy,   Black,  2017-01-22
5, Bob,  Samsung, Galaxy,   Black,  2017-01-28
6, Jane, Apple,   iPhone 6, Silver, 2017-01-18
7, Jane, Apple,   iPhone 6, Silver, 2017-01-22
8, Jane, Samsung, Galaxy,   White,  2017-01-28
```

I'd like to retrieve display a list like so:

```
2, Bob,  Apple,   iPhone 6, Silver, 2017-01-09
3, Bob,  Apple,   iPhone 6, Gold,   2017-01-18
7, Jane, Apple,   iPhone 6, Silver, 2017-01-22
8, Jane, Samsung, Galaxy,   White,  2017-01-28
```

So that I can see the latest date of purchase for each variation of a phone.

I tried `GROUP BY brand, model, color`, but it doesn't return the latest row as ordering before group is not supported(?).

Please let me know if I can clear anything up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770936/

Comment: @JohnEllmore Looks like the most efficient route. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the laravel query builder

```
$purchases = DB::table('Purchases')
            ->groupBy('brand', 'model', 'color')
            ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$date = array();
foreach ($purchase as $key => $row)
{
    $date[$key] = $row['date'];
}
array_multisort($date, SORT_ASC, $purchase);
```

Comment: If this was the correct resolving advice, it would have been more appropriate to close this question as a duplicate instead of answering.  [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.) However, this answer only sorts by one column, but the requirement is different.