# Finding latest row for each foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I have got two tables - **Conversations** and **Messages**, each conversation has many messages. We have to find the latest message for each Conversation.

[ER-Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LxMb.jpg)

I have tried join and "group by converstion_id" but it provides me the oldest messages.

Help me out with SQL query with respect to the MySQL.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. (Obviously). See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do ask, because it's not a duplicate, please act on [mcve]. Please use text, not images/links, for text. Act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score -1):

The underlying problem here is that you want to order the data you'are grouping on before the GROUP BY is executed. This question is asked, and answered, before.

[MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)