# SQL query to find out Avg. Salary on Location wise

Tags: sql

SQL query to find out Avg Salary location wise ?

```
Name|Location|Salary
====|========|======
a   |Bombay  |4000
b   |Bombay  |5000
c   |Delhi   |3000
d   |Delhi   |6000
e   |Chennai |700
f   |Chennai |9000
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

use `average` and `group by` to get your result.

```
 select location , avg(salary) as Average from table group by location
```

You may find this link for more info [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: . . .  `DISTINCT` is not very helpful when using `GROUP by` clause.