# SQL ORDER BY GROUP

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

```
question category 
A           X
B           Y
C           X
D           X
E           Y
```

I want to make the output from the most frequent category

```
question category
A             X
C             X
D             X
B             Y
E             Y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Answer (score 3):

You could try with join on the count for category

```
select m.question, m.category  
from my_table  m
inner join  (
  select category, count(*) num
  from my_table  
   group by category 
) t on t.category = m.category
order by t.num desc, m.category, m.question
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this. This avoids the need for a join.

```
select *
from mytable
order by 
    count(*) over(partition by category) desc,
    question
```

Answer (score -4):

Use order by category.

select * from [table] order by category

Comment: This will just order them, but will not put the one that happens the most at the top