# MySQL: How to order the data in each group?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
| Key | Value | Message |
|-----|-------|---------|
| a   | 1     | xx      |
| a   | 2     | yy      |
| b   | 5     | mm      |
| b   | 4     | nn      |
```

I would like to group the data by Key, get the minimum Value of each group, and the related Message.
The result is expected to be:

```
| Key | Value | Message |
|-----|-------|---------|
| a   | 1     | xx      |
| b   | 4     | nn      |
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename a
where value = (select min(value) from tablename b where a.key=b.key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by key order by value) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

You can also use correlated `subquery` if ranking function not support :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.value = (select min(t1.value) from table t1 where t1.key = t.key);
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to handle this in MySQL 5.7 or earlier would be to join to a subquery which finds the smallest value for each key:

```
SELECT t1.`Key`, t1.`Value`, t1.Message
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `Key`, MIN(`Value`) AS min_value
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY `Key`
) t2
    ON t1.`Key` = t2.`Key` AND t1.`Value` = t2.min_value
ORDER BY
    t1.`Key`;
```

*Please* try to avoid naming your columns and other database objects using reserved SQL keywords, such as `Key` and `Value`.  You may consider the need to type backticks in a MySQL query as an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First create a subquery that returns `min value` for each `key`, then join with the main table:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
inner join (
   select key, min(value) min_value
   from tablename
   group by key
) i on i.key = t.key and i.min_value = t.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query

```
select * from table_name tab1
where value in ( select MIN(value) from table_name tab2
                where tab2.[key] = tab1.[key] )
```