# MAX() as a filtering clause for a LEFT JOIN, Are there any alternatives?

Tags: sql, sqlite, max, left-join

It seems to me that there is another option for this query, but I cannot pinpoint exactly what is that option:

```
@Query("" +
        "SELECT " +
        "... not really important... " +
        "FROM (" +
        "SELECT ect.* " +
        "FROM element_constant_table ect " +
        "WHERE book_parent_id = :bookId AND availability = 1" +
        ") ect1 " +
        "LEFT JOIN " +
        "element_version_table evt " +
        "ON (" +
            "SELECT evt.element_parent_id " +
            "WHERE " +
            "evt.time = (" +
                "SELECT MAX(evt2.time) " +
                "FROM element_version_table evt2 " +
                "WHERE evt2.element_parent_id = evt.element_parent_id" +
            ") " +
        ") = ect1.element_id" +
        "")
public abstract LiveData<List<Element>> getLatestElementsAt(int bookId);
```

For readability:

```
        SELECT 
        ... not really important... 
        FROM (
        SELECT ect.* 
        FROM element_constant_table ect 
        WHERE book_parent_id = :bookId AND availability = 1
        ) ect1 
        LEFT JOIN 
        element_version_table evt 
        ON (
            SELECT evt.element_parent_id 
            WHERE 
            evt.time = (
                SELECT MAX(evt2.time) 
                FROM element_version_table evt2 
                WHERE evt2.element_parent_id = evt.element_parent_id
            ) 
        ) = ect1.element_id
```

The MAX() function is forcing a new instantiation of the whole `element_version_table` for each row found on `element_constant_table`.

I was aware that something like this may happen so I always try to filter the table before it reaches the LEFT JOIN, in this case with the clause `"WHERE book_parent_id = :bookId AND availability = 1"`

There is no way to filter the LEFT TABLE and make it coincide with its corresponding key on the RIGHT TABLE before the ON clause, and so the WHERE needs to be placed there.

The problem is that if instead of using the MAX(), I use a simple ORDER BY evt.time DESC LIMIT 1 inside the ON clause the compiler tells me that there is no evt.time field (I assume that it does not exist **YET**).
So my conclusions to this are:

**a) An ORDER BY requires for the table to be instantiated to its full length (It does not happens during the process of row location).**

**b) The ON clause happens BEFORE the LEFT TABLE reaches instantiation (what I assume is) to it's full length.**

Are my conclusions about the order of clause execution correct?

How much of a burden may this query be on an extensive Database? and
What would a better option be?

Comment: `SELECT evt.element_parent_id WHERE...` where is the FROM clause?

Comment: Yes, I had that same doubt, but the query actually works, the table is from the one being LEFT JOIN'ed called "element_version_table evt".... Oh is that the reason why evt.time not found???

Comment: Maybe it works, but your query is not readable. Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below sql query to retrieve live data of book in your code:

```
     SELECT 
    ... not really important... 
    FROM element_constant_table ect 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT evt.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY evt.element_parent_id ORDER BY evt.time DESC) as seqnum 
    from element_version_table evt) evt_final on ect.element_id = evt_final.element_parent_id and evt_final.seqnum=1
    where ect.book_parent_id = :bookId AND ect.availability = 1
```

I am finding here latest book record from "element_version_table" if exists.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite window function ROW_NUMBER() can be a solution to your problem.

https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/

You didn't provide full details of your tables. But, depending on size of your element_version table and query performance, you can try:

```
SELECT 
    ... not really important...  FROM
    (SELECT ect.*
    FROM element_constant_table ect
    WHERE book_parent_id=:bookId AND availability=1
    ) ect1

    LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT t.*
     FROM
        (SELECT
            evt.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY element_parent_id ORDER BY evt.time DESC) rn
         FROM element_version_table evt) t
     WHERE t.rn = 1
    ) evt1

    ON ect1.element_id = evt1.element_parent_id
```

or

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ... not really important...,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ect1.element_id, evt1.element_parent_id ORDER BY evt1.time DESC) rn

    FROM
        (SELECT ect.*
        FROM element_constant_table ect
        WHERE book_parent_id=:bookId AND availability=1
        ) ect1

        LEFT JOIN element_version_table evt1
        ON ect1.element_id = evt1.element_parent_id
    ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer, I'm sure this works but the solutions works for versions of SQLite that are from, and beyond 3.25.0, mine is at 3.19, But the ROW_NUMBER = 1 is very clever as it avoids cropping the table before ON correlation. and the PARTITION BY works as a kind of GROUP BY, this means that you are effectively filtering the left table to give you the top element_parent_id's and each group ordered by time, and I think there is no way to do that in 3.19. before the ON takes place.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

## **This solution would be for SQLite versions < 3.25.0**

Thanks to user @armamut That gave the original idea and this other question from 7 years ago [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14770671/11214643).

```
@Query("" +
        "SELECT " +
        ... not really important ...
        "FROM (" +
            "SELECT ect.* " +
            "FROM element_constant_table ect " +
            "WHERE book_parent_id = :bookId AND availability = 1" +
        ") ect1 " +
        "LEFT JOIN " +
        "(" +
            "SELECT " +
                "evt.*," +
                "MAX(evt.time) " +
            "FROM element_version_table evt " +
            "GROUP BY evt.element_parent_id" +
        ") evt1 " +
        "ON evt1.element_parent_id = ect1.element_id" +
        "")
public abstract LiveData<List<Element>> getLatestElementsAt(int bookId);
```

For readability:

```
        SELECT 
        ... not really important ...
        FROM (
            SELECT ect.* 
            FROM element_constant_table ect 
            WHERE book_parent_id = :bookId AND availability = 1
        ) ect1 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                evt.*,
                MAX(evt.time) 
            FROM element_version_table evt 
            GROUP BY evt.element_parent_id
        ) evt1 
        ON evt1.element_parent_id = ect1.element_id
```