# SQL: How to get a every maximum value of a table?

Tags: sql, join, sum, max

I have a huge table called 'Sales` with these areas

```
Time  | Product  | amount | customerid
Date1 | Product1 | 2      | 2
Date1 | Product2 | 5      | 3
Date1 | Product1 | 6      | 3
Date1 | Product4 | 1      | 3
Date2 | Product1 | 2      | 1
Date2 | Product1 | 2      | 4
Date2 | Product3 | 3      | 4
Date2 | Product3 | 3      | 1
```

Now, I want to get a most popular product each day.

```
SELECT  Time, 
        Product, 
        SUM(amount) AS Total 
FROM Sales 
     GROUP BY Time, Product
```

Gives me the following

```
Time  | Product  | total
Date1 | Product1 | 8
Date1 | Product2 | 5
Date1 | Product4 | 1
Date2 | Product1 | 4
Date2 | Product4 | 6
```

In which way I have to change my query, to get just the top seller products of each day?

EDIT: Thanks a lot for your solutions, but it doesn't work.
I want to summerize, which product is a top seller of each day

   `Time   | Product  | total

    Date1 | Product1 | 8

    Date2 | Product4 | 6`
Stuff like 'LIMIT 1' just show me the first row, but not all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448504/mysql-group-by-and-sort-each-group     OR `SELECT Time, Product, amount AS Total FROM Sales Order by time DESC, amout desc`

Comment: Hint: Try googling the tags you assigned, especially that last one.

Comment: Which DB are you going to use this for..?

Answer (score 3):

Try this query. Rank function implementation is different in different DB's.

```
SELECT TIME, PRODUCT
FROM (
SELECT TIME, PRODUCT, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM_AMOUNT) AS SELECT_TOP
FROM 
(
(
      SELECT 
      TIME
     , PRODUCT
     , SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_AMOUNT
     FROM Sales 
GROUP BY TIME, PRODUCT ) TBL1 ) TBL2
WHERE
SELECT_TOP = 1
```

Comment: +1 (although you have a minor syntax error - check parenthesis count).  Note that, as the OP hasn't currently listed his RDBMS, this _might_ not work in his situation; however most of the larger vendors can handle this.  Also, depending on how the OP wants to handle ties (...also unspecified...), `RANK()` may need to be switched out for one of the other functions.

Comment: Hi Prashanth. I am using PostgreSQL und your advice doesn't work in a correct way. It shows me not all the dates I have in my table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Time, Product, SUM(amount) AS Total FROM Sales GROUP BY Time, Product order by sum(amount) DESC;
```

Comment: The asker just want the topseller products

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Time, Product, SUM(amount) AS Total FROM Sales GROUP BY Time, Product ORDER BY Total DESC limit 1
```

I use `ORDER BY Total DESC` to sort `Total` column by descending so the largest value of `Total` column is in the top. Therefore, I just take the largest one by `limit 1`

Comment: `SELECT Time, Product, SUM(amount) AS Total FROM Sales GROUP BY Time, Product ORDER BY time Desc, Total DESC`

Comment: @Jan Czarny instead of comment here, please to add another answer

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT 
       Time, Product, SUM(amount) AS Total 
FROM Sales 
       GROUP BY Time, Product 
       ORDER BY time Desc, Total DESC
```